# Free blocks count wrong when using e2fsck

Tags: ubuntu, lvm

I have 2 disks attached to my server, one is fixed and the other can be expanded. I have these disks added to a volume group with LVM and linux mounted on top of it. When I want to grow the space of my volume group, I expand one of the disks and create a new partition on it, then I expand the vg.

```
fdisk /dev/sda -> create a new partition (number 2) of type LVM (8E)
pvcreate /dev/sda2
vgextend vg0 /dev/sda2
lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/vg0/root
```

Then I expand the filesystem with the following command

```
resize2fs /dev/vg0/root
```

But it says: "Please run 'e2fsck -f /dev/vg0/root' first."

When I run that command, I get the following conflicts

```
e2fsck 1.47.0 (5-Feb-2023)
/dev/vg0/root: recovering journal
Clearing orphaned inode 131099 (uid=113, gid=119, mode=0100660, size=0)
Clearing orphaned inode 131098 (uid=113, gid=119, mode=0100660, size=0)
Clearing orphaned inode 131097 (uid=113, gid=119, mode=0100660, size=0)
Clearing orphaned inode 131096 (uid=113, gid=119, mode=0100660, size=0)
Clearing orphaned inode 131095 (uid=0, gid=0, mode=0100666, size=0)
Clearing orphaned inode 131094 (uid=0, gid=0, mode=0100666, size=0)
Clearing orphaned inode 131093 (uid=0, gid=0, mode=0100666, size=0)
Clearing orphaned inode 131092 (uid=0, gid=0, mode=0100666, size=0)
Clearing orphaned inode 131091 (uid=0, gid=0, mode=0100666, size=0)
Clearing orphaned inode 131090 (uid=0, gid=0, mode=0100666, size=0)
Clearing orphaned inode 131088 (uid=0, gid=0, mode=0100666, size=0)
Clearing orphaned inode 131087 (uid=0, gid=0, mode=0100666, size=0)
Clearing orphaned inode 131086 (uid=0, gid=0, mode=0100666, size=0)
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information
Free blocks count wrong (74047853, counted=74043700).
Fix<y>?
```

If I go ahead and fix everything, it works, but I am not sure if that is normal or I am doing anything wrong.

Do you know why I am having these conflicts? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Did your system maybe crash some time in the past?

Comment: No, this is a new fresh install of Ubuntu 22.04